# Is it called in BrE - switch or button?

Tags: british-english, image-identification

I saw two translations for this thing and I'd like to know if it's called **switch** or **button** in British English.

> "She touched the **?_** and she was electrocuted."

[image]

Comment: What do you think it controls?

Comment: An electrical circuit?

Comment: In American English, that thing in the picture would be called **a light switch**. I'm pretty sure it's the same for British English.

Comment: If you rock it from one position - off - to another position - on - it is a switch in BrE. A button is pressed.

Comment: Generally, you push a button but flip a switch. Of course technically they are all switches.

Comment: "Flip" a switch is predominantly a US idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a *(light) switch* in Br Eng, same in US Eng.

One difference is that in Britain "down" is "on",  but in the USA "down" is "off". (The switches in your image would be "up" and so "off" in Britain.)

Comment: That depends on how the circuit controlling the light is wired up, some lights such as landing lights have more than one controlling switch  one at the bottom of the stairs and one at the top meaning that any one particular switch can be on or off when it's down or up.